# How to use Webkit browser with watiN

Tags: c#, winforms, webkit, watin, geckofx

i am working on an winform application in which i used watiN. Now when i open my website in default winform browser control, than its design become worst. So i want to use Webkit Browser control in my winform app.
I don't know how to use Webkit Browser in watiN.
I also tried to use GeckoFX for it , but it is also not supporting in watiN.
Can anybody please tell me how can i use other browser controls in watin except Default winform browser control. 
I am stucked here

Thanks in Advance

Comment: WatiN is for Web application and does not support (full fledged)  Win controls. There is a class in WatiN which supports a very minimal functionality for Windows.

Comment: Watin.Core Supporting winform browser control @Sham

Comment: `WatiN.Core.Native.Windows` is the class which supports Windows. But if you look at it methods, it has very minimal support.

Comment: I Just wanted to know How can i use ActivexInstance property in webkit browser. Because in WatiN when i use default winform browser than i have to use its ActiveXInstance with IE().@Sham